# Calculating Gross from a desired Net

Tags: united-states, income-tax, self-employment, sole-proprietorship

I have a sole proprietorship and I'm helping out a friend. We have an agreement where I told him what I needed to net each month and I can invoice for that.

If I need to net $6000 each month, how do I calculate the gross amount that needs to be invoiced so I can end up netting $6000?

I've seen a lot of calculators on line for the self employment portion, but also need to factor in state (CA)/fed income taxes, as well as anything else I might be missing. This doesn't need to be exact, I just want to be able to generate an invoice for more than $6k so that by the time I pay taxes on 2019, I will have taken home the $6k that month.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's what I've tried so far:

- [FICA percentage](https://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/calculate-fica-sole-proprietorship-2935.html): 15.3%
- Employer Equivalent Portion (which I can subtract): 7.65%
- Marginal Tax Rate [(on $72k)](https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/calcs/marginal-tax-rate-calculator.php): 12%

**Calculate Self Employment Tax**

(6,000 * .9235) * .153 = $847.77

**Calculate Income Tax**

(6,000 + 847.77) * 100/(100-12) = $7,781.56

I would need to invoice for **$7,781.56**

Am I getting close with this line of thought?

Comment: Do you have other income?

Comment: This depends on the applicable tax percentages. If your *marginal* tax rate is p%, then you want x*(1-p/100)= 1000, or x = 1000*100/(100-p)

Comment: For these purposes, no, I will not have other income.

Comment: @djibouti33, that's not how taxes work.  Other income is required to determine which marginal tax bracket this income will fall in to.

Comment: @quid, absolutely. I meant to say I won't have other income outside what I'm billing my friend, so I can project for 12 months to calculate my marginal tax rate.

Comment: @quid I just updated my question with a possible direction

Comment: Why don't you just plug in some numbers on a 1040 with Schedules C and SE (and any others you might need) along with your state return and then you'll know for certain? That shouldn't take more than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution that works for my purposes.

1. Figure out your Federal effective tax rate
2. Figure out your State effective tax rate
3. As a sole proprietor, you're responsible both sides of the self employment tax, 15.3%. Determine if you want to use all or 1/2 (what you'd pay if you were a W2 employee. My accountant recommended I use half, 7.65%)

Then:

Net / (1 - (Fed + State + Self Employment)/100)

So if I wanted to net $6000, with Fed=15%, State = 5%, and Self Employment =7.65%:

6000/(1-(27.65/100)) = **$8,293.02**